# query dependent on two other tables and one column

Tags: sql, dependencies

I need to get one row from a table that depends on two other conditions, so I'm searching for a nice query to solve my problem if this is possible.

**Description**
A `level` is part of a `series`. A `player` can finish a `level` (saved in table `players_levels_done`).
Within a `series` the `level`s are sorted using the `order` column. The lowest order number is the first level to be solved.
Now I want to get the `level_id` of the next level which a player needs to solve.

**Example #1**

> Player 9 has already finished level 5. Since level 5 is the lowest order, the query should return the `level_id` 4, because it's the next unsolved level in series 1 for this specific user.

**Example #2**

> Player 19 has finished level 11. But level 11 is not the firstly ordered level in the series, so the query should return `level_id` 12.

If a player solved all levels of a series, the query should return a total row count of 0.

**Table `levels`**

```
id (level_id) | series_id | order
--------------+-----------+------
4             | 1         | 20
5             | 1         | 10
6             | 1         | 30
11            | 2         | 60
12            | 2         | 50
13            | 2         | 70
```

**Table `players_levels_done`**

```
player_id | level_id
----------+---------
9         | 5
19        | 11
```

**Table `series`**

```
id (series_id) | ...
---------------+----
1              | ...
2              | ...
```

**Table `players`**

```
id (player_id) | ...
---------------+----
9              | ...
19             | ...
```

Comment: I'm just curious. Any reason why you would not do this as two queries?

Comment: Well, yes. Speed and much easier handling of the SQL data in the program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an answer. And it works!!

I changed order to level_order to work with it in mysql.

[Here is the same in SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8c4e7/1) to try out.

```
select 
  pout.player_id, lout.id
from
      levels as lout,
      players_levels_done as pout
where 
  lout.level_order in ( 
    select 
      min(l1.level_order )
    from 
      levels as l1,
      players_levels_done as p1
    where
      l1.id not in 
        (
            select 
              level_id 
            from 
              players_levels_done 
            where 
              player_id = p1.player_id
         )
      and
      l1.series_id =
        (
           select 
            distinct l.series_id 
          from 
            levels as l,
            players_levels_done as p
          where
            p.level_id = l.id
            and 
             player_id = p1. player_id
        )
    and p1.player_id = pout.player_id
    group by p1.player_id
  )
;
```

Comment: ooh.. noticed that this does not do very well.. it only selects the min of the id, but not the id with min level_order.  will see if i can solve that..

Comment: Thanks! But it seems to return false values. For player 9 this is correct. But if I add a row for player 9 (in players_levels_done), it returns an error: "More than one subrow returned". Also, if I change level_id from 5 to 6 in players_levels_done, it returns level_id 4, which is wrong :-/

Comment: updated to fix "more than one subrow" And yes, like I mentioned above, it does not give the id with lowest level_order. Will try to fix that.